# Deploying google cloud function with access to private nuget repository from Google cloud build with secret manager

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, nuget, google-cloud-build

Do you know is it possible to deploy google cloud function to not store private nuget credentials in the code but rather to keep them in secret manager?
I was trying to achieve it like this:

```bash
λ gcloud functions deploy function_name --entry-point Function \ 
--region europe-west1 --trigger-http --project project_name \ 
--set-env-vars ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production \
--set-secrets 'DEPLOY_API_KEY=DEPLOY_API_KEY:latest' \
--set-secrets 'NUGET_USER=NUGET_USER:latest'
```

But it seems google cloud build doesn't map the environment variables with secrets.
Here is nuget.config file that I am using (it works when credentials are hardcoded).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <!-- make sure other nuget.config files don't add unexpected sources -->
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="private" value="<private_nuget_url>" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <private>
            <add key="Username" value="%NUGET_USER%" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%DEPLOY_API_KEY%" />
        </private>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Google Cloud Build service agent has enabled api to access secret manager:
[image]

Comment: "it works when credentials are hardcoded" How did you do this? I can't seem to get cloud function to read even a hardcoded nuget.config file.

Answer (score 0):

The secret that you set in your Cloud Functions deploy command are set at runtime, not at build time. You can't achieve what you want to do with Cloud Functions.

I recommend you to switch to Cloud Run to control the build of the container with Cloud Build and to load the secret through [Cloud Build - Secret Manager integration](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets)